# Time to first jump for doubly stochastic poisson process (cox process)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, poisson-distribution

Let $N_t$ denote a doubly stochastic Poisson (Cox) process with intensity process $\lambda_t$. [Lando (1998)](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/ebf6f179d9bd3bf0c1257911006c47f7/$FILE/Lando%20-%201998%20-%20On%20Cox%20processes%20and%20credit%20risky%20securities.pdf) defines the time to first jump $\tau$ as:

$$\tau = \inf\{ t: \int_{0}^{t} \lambda_u du \geq E_1  \} $$

where $E_1$ is a unit exponential random variable. Why is this a good definition for a time to first jump? I can't figure it out yet.

Further, I will redefine $\tau$ to be just the "time for first jump" as I would normally imagine it to be. Then $P(\tau > t) = P(N_t = 0)$. Then, given that the distribution of a Cox process is:

$$ P(N_t - N_s = k) = \frac{(\int_s^t \lambda_u du)^k}{k!}e^{(-\int_s^t \lambda_u du)}  $$

If we set $s=0$ and $k = 0$, then:

$$P(\tau > t) = P(N_t = 0) = e^{(-\int_s^t \lambda_u du)} $$

Why is it wrong to just solve the integral above? I would imagine that maybe it can't be solve for all cases, but maybe for some notable ones.

Comment: Of course the first jump time is $\inf\{s\in(0,t] : N_{s-} \neq N_s\}$. What is crucial is that $\tau$ defined by Lando is equal in distribution to the first jump time. Later in the paper, Lando introduces similar jump times to obtain a construction and simulation algorithm (see p. 13). To my understanding, the introduction of $\tau$ is not that different than the usual link between Poisson processes and exponentially distributed inter-arrival times: it is just two ways to represent the same thing, the second one being useful for e.g. simulation purposes.